# Standard way of typing a set of equations in math mode involving two relations, for example: $=$ and $<$

Tags: math-mode, formatting, math-operators

When typing a set of equations in math mode, is it better/clearer/standard to type, for example, how Rudin types this equation (pg 15 'baby Rudin'):

[image]

Notice, how the third line changes to $\le$ and then the fourth line changes back to $=$. My guess is that each line on the RHS implies the next line on the RHS only.

Or is it better/clearer/standard to have, for example, my work:
[image]

Notice how I changed to $\le$ in the fourth line and kept $\le$ all the way through. My reasoning is because each line implies the next line.

Comment: This might be off topic here. In any case, I would personally use the first form, only using `\leq` when necessary. The only rule, of course, you can only put `=` in the same line (like the first line of the first form), if there's a `\leq` it has to be in the vertically aligned symbols.

Comment: @Manuel Why is this question off topic?

Comment: @AlJebr The reason is that the question isn't really *about* TeX-LaTeX. If you were asking how to do one or the other in TeX-LaTeX that'd be very different. But this is really more of a layout/typography question, and/or arguably a question about how to read and write mathematics. As such, it's not only not really a LaTeX question (in fact it's quite far from that, you could ask the question without mentioning LaTeX at all and nothing really would change), but there's also not really a right answer, it's quite opinion based and such questions are usually a bad fit for the site :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good question! I believe the former way is a bit more clearer than the latter and here is why:

You state your reason for presenting the math like that is because each line implies the next. However, in the way Rudin presents it, each line still implies the next. In fact, his presentation is actually stronger. For example, $p \leq q$ is not as strong as stating $p=q$. By writing $p=q$, we are making a more precise statement which is better.

Comment: [Welcome to LaTeX! Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)